# VS 2017 Command line error D8004

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, suppress-warnings

I'm out of options, I'm trying to work with GoogleTest on Visual Studio 2017 Community but it gives me a lot of

> warning C4996: 'std::tr1': warning STL4002: The non-Standard std::tr1
>   namespace and TR1-only machinery are deprecated and will be REMOVED.
>   You can define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING to
>   acknowledge that you have received this warning.

I want to supress it, so I go under my Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Supress Specific Warnings and I try

```
/wd4996
/wdSTL4002,
/wd4996;
/wdC4996
/wd[4996]...
```

etc, I honestly tried every possible combination and it throws me

> 2>cl : Command line error D8004: '/wd' requires an argument

Could someone send me exactly what I need to write there to supress this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the error message, you can add a `#define` equivalent to the command line:

```
/D:_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING
```

That is the equivalent of inserting before the first line of the source files

```
#define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING  1
```

Comment: Well adding `#define` to precompiled header worked, any ideas why VS didnt want to cooperate tho?

Comment: Still getting the error after adding the define at the top of the file.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the following steps:

1. Click View in the tool baar.
2. Select  properties.. at  the bottom.

3.Select c/c++ -> Preprocessor.

4.Set Preprocessor Definitions as _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING

Answer (score 1):

Silencing warnings is never a good option. In this case warning about `tr1` seems to arise from incorrect project configuration. You can try defining `GTEST_LANG_CXX11` to make gtest use stuff from `std` namespace or track origins of those warnings and figure out why are they still issued.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has an answer already, but to answer your question specifically, if you simply add 4996, as opposed to /wd[4996] (or any other variation of that).

All you need to add is 4996.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by going into `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions` and adding `_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING` to the preprocessor definitions:
[image]

After this gtest was finally built successfully.

Adding `#define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING 1` at the top of the file and in the Additional Preprocesor Definitions when I click on the project didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change the project settings, you can add #define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING 1
to the stdafx.h if you have one.
It worked for me.